# Prestashop hookActionCustomerAccountAdd doesn't fire up in admin section

Tags: php, hook, prestashop-1.6

i want to send some ata to an API once a user register on prestashop.

It's working perfectly in the front but in the Back office the event don't fire up ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

In front office, when a customer registers it executes the hook actionCustomerAccountAdd

```
Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                            '_POST' => $_POST,
                            'newCustomer' => $customer
                        ));
```

In the back office, it doesn't execute such hook (or any other hook). But you can create an override in override/controllers/admin/AdminCustomersController.php

```
class AdminCustomersController extends AdminCustomersControllerCore
{
    public function processAdd()
    {
        $customer = parent::processAdd();
        if($customer === false)
             return false;

        // else do what you need here

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to, instead of using the hook actionCustomerAccountAdd, you can override the customer add function that would be executed everytime a customer is added, no matter where it is created (unless it's added in database and not using the prestashop function). In override/classes/Customer.php:

```
class Customer extends CustomerCore
{
    public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = true)
    {
        $res = parent::add($autodate, $null_values);
        if(!$res)
             return $res; // customer not added

        // do what you need. $this is the customer just added
    }
}
```

If you use an override, don't forget to delete the file cache/class_index.php

Comment: @sadlyblue Sorry, but your answer isn't entirely correct. While yes you can solve the problem with overrides, there is an admin hook for these actions [actionAdminAddAfter](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/controller/AdminController.php#L929) and [actionAdminCustomersControllerAddAfter](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/controller/AdminController.php#L930). Also when objects are being added you can use hook [actionObjectCustomerAddAfter](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/ObjectModel.php#L537).

Comment: @TheDrot You are right. Didn't remember the hook executed "automatically" when objected are added. I will update my answer later. And yes, overrides should be only used if there is no other way.